# Sharepoint - Download editable file from url in chrome

Tags: sharepoint

We have been stuck on using Internet Explorer in my company for one single reason: when you click on a sharepoint link to a Document in IE, it opens the file as *editable*. So when you save it, it is automatically saved on the server.

On the other hand, with Chrome or other browsers, it downloads a *copy* of this file, so the user might loose changes because he thinks the file is saved on the server whereas really it is not...

Anyone thinks of a solution for that?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar resolved question to yours right here:

**[How to open SharePoint files in Chrome/Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455212/how-to-open-sharepoint-files-in-chrome-firefox)**

give it a shot!