# Edit in office button in SharePoint site

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ms-office, sharepoint-2013

In a SharePoint project I am working on that shows files, we have a button to open the `SPFile` that the user is seeing in office.
Currently, the button is working for IE only. I have to make it available for chrome and firefox also (currently it is just saving the file instead of opening it in these browsers).
I know this is possible because when you open the file from SharePoint home page it does open in office.
I have searched for solutions and found one that uses Application URL protocol for word [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30929451/3503590) but unfortunately that doesn't work for my case because I need to know when the user closes the document to refresh the age to show changes :(

here is the code we are using: (note that this link is called through `javascript`

```html
<a id="OfficeUrl" onclick="g_varSkipRefreshOnFocus = 0;fromOffice = true;if(isIE){window.onfocus = RefreshOnFocus;browseris.ie=true;}DispEx(this, event, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3', '1', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', '', '', $('[id$=CheckedOutUserHidden]').val(), $('[id$=UserIdHidden]').val(), '0', '0', '0x7fffffffffffffff', '', '');if(!isIE){window.onfocus = RefreshOnFocus;}g_varSkipRefreshOnFocus = 0;return false;" href="" style="display: none;"></a>
```

[Edit] I forgot to tell you that we are referencing `SP.CORE.js` and `SP.INIT.js` (however they seem different from the ones located in `\layouts\15\sp.init.js`- looks like they are from `SharePoint-2010` because the version of `sp.init.js` is `14.0.4762`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work in chrome.
What I did is that I used the `\_layouts\15\CORE.js` and `\_layouts\15\INIT.js` and I surrounded the a tag with

```html
<div ctxname="ctx1" app="ms-word">
    <a id="OfficeUrl" onclick="g_varSkipRefreshOnFocus = 0;fromOffice = true;if(isIE){window.onfocus = RefreshOnFocus;browseris.ie=true;}DispEx(this, event, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3', '1', 'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', '', '', $('[id$=CheckedOutUserHidden]').val(), $('[id$=UserIdHidden]').val(), '0', '0', '0x7fffffffffffffff', '', '');if(!isIE){window.onfocus = RefreshOnFocus;}g_varSkipRefreshOnFocus = 0;return false;" href="" style="display: none;"></a>
</div>
```

Hope it helps someone
I now need to know how to do it for firefox (looks like sharepoint does not support it? because it does not open from sharepoint).